# How can I display the value using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Hi. I need help with this section of code.

What I want to do is; when I click (for example) a radio button 1, that button value display on the browser. I have a three radio buttons.

Here's my ajax query:

```
function updatepayment(this.value)()
var ajaxResponse = new Object();
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rmr').click(function () {
    var rbVal = $(this).val();
        var myContent;
        if (ajaxResponse[rbVal]) { //in cache
          myContent =  ajaxResponse[rbVal];
          $("#contentcontainer").html(myContent);
        }
        else { // not in cache
      var urlForAjaxCall = "include/function.php" + rbVal + ".html"; 
          $.post(urlForAjaxCall, function (myContent) {
             ajaxResponse[rbVal] = myContent;
             $("#contentcontainer").html(myContent);
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It looks like the response is not an object. Use `json` as type for `$.post`.

Comment: Can you atleast post the rest of HTML/JS?

Comment: <form method="post" form name="make_payment_frm" action="module/make-payment-module.php" onsubmit="return show_make_payment_validation();" > <input type="hidden" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="<?php echo get_total_amount();?>" /> <input type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment1" value="3" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /> <input type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment2" value="5.5" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /> <input type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment4" value="10" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /> <div id="finalamount"> </div>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){  
                           $("input[name=rmr]").click(function()
                                                               {  
if( $("input[name=rmr]:checked").length > 0 ) //make sure one is checked    
{    
$("#finalamount").html( $("#totalamount").val() * $("input[name=rmr]:checked").val() );    
     } 
        }); 
         });

Comment: hello all, i have an error value / "NaN" value that's i;m not expecting of..

i have showed my html/js please tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Your cache check will always be false since you always re-declare ajaxResponse in the function. ajaxResponse should be declared globally.
2. And you dont really need the post function (as your not posting any data) you could just use the .load function.
3. You dont need a function to wrap the $(document).ready function

> var ajaxResponse = new Object();
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
> $('.rmr').click(function (){
>     var rbVal = $(this).val();
>     var myContent;
>     if (ajaxResponse[rbVal]) 
>     { //in cache
>         $("#contentcontainer").html(  ajaxResponse[rbVal] );
>     }
>     else 
>     { // not in cache
>         var urlForAjaxCall = "include/function.php" + rbVal + ".html"; 
>         $("#contentcontainer").load(urlForAjaxCall, function (myContent) 
>         {
>             //Extra processing can be done here, like your cache
>             ajaxResponse[rbVal] = myContent;
>         });
>     }
> ```
>
> > });
>
> });

**EDIT:**
After seeing your comments on your OP 
You are trying to select the radio buttons by class name "rmr" but do not have it set on the tags
you need:

```
<input class="rmr" type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment1" value="3" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /> <br>
<input class="rmr" type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment2" value="5.5" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /><br>
<input class="rmr" type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment4" value="10" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" /><br>
```

or you could use

`$("input[name=rmr]")`

to select them by their input name attribute